# Fix No module named 'openai_whisper'

Tags: python

I have installed the package `openai_whisper` using this line

```
pip install openai-whisper
```

But when I used this line in the code `import openai_whisper`, I got an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai_whisper'`.

I also tried this line but with no use `python -m pip install openai-whisper`

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Comment: No. just notepad++

Comment: Open python terminal and try importing there.

Comment: How do you run your code? What command?

Comment: I recommend that you [read the documentation](https://github.com/openai/whisper) for the correct `import` statement. If you are following a tutorial that says to write `import openai_whisper`, I suggest that you find a different tutorial.

Comment: If you import whisper and import openai, it should work.

Comment: I am using command prompt to run the code. I tried `import whisper` but got `\whisper\timing.py:57: NumbaDeprecationWarning: The 'nopython' keyword argument was not supplied to the 'numba.jit' decorator. The implicit default value for this argument is currently False, but it will be changed to True in Numba 0.59.0.` and also tried `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'`

Comment: I tried python terminal and I got the same error. I even created new environment but no use.

Answer (score 2):

After you installed the module. Try importing using `import whisper` instead of import openai_whisper it works.

If it is not working then probably it will be an environment issue. The module you installed will be installed to a different python environment than what you are using right now.

If you are using VScode press crtl + shift + P to choose python interpreter and change the environment accrodingly.

Comment: I tried your line but got an error `C:\Users\Future\Desktop\myenv\Lib\site-packages\whisper\timing.py:57: NumbaDeprecationWarning: The 'nopython' keyword argument was not supplied to the 'numba.jit' decorator. The implicit default value for this argument is currently False, but it will be changed to True in Numba 0.59.0. See https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit for details.
  @numba.jit`

Comment: Could you add more information. This is not an issue with the importing whisper as it seems.